# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to make my first React Native Android app and I am getting this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;    

    return (
      <View>
        <Button 
          title="Show Centers near me"
          onPress={() =>
            navigate('Results', "Search Term")
          }
          />
        <Text>or</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


class ResultsScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Results',
  };


  render() {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hi</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Results: { screen: ResultsScreen }
});
```

I can not figure out why the error is coming.

Comment: Try adding a constructor in your class like so: `constructor(props) { super(props) }`

Comment: @HelderJulesDeBaere Doesn't help!

Comment: Show more code around how you setup the StackNavigator. this.props.navigation is passed down by the navigator and if the setup is off then this error may happen. Also try searching on SO for this, this has been answered a lot.

Comment: @hyb175 I have added the StackNavigator setup. I have thoroughly searched SO and Google before posting this. None of the suggested solutions worked for me.

Comment: This is still not enough information to help you. Try putting more complete setup so people can recreate this issue you have. Something to check first, is HomeScreen component used anywhere else besides in the StackNavigator call?

Comment: @hyb175 I have added the complete code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are exporting the component wrong. You should get rid of the `export default` on your `class HomeScreen` definition and at the bottom of the file do `export default App;`

Answer (score 2):

If you are handling it in AppContainer and not able to access while opening drawer menu. You can try below snippets.

```
const HomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({   Home:    { 
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions : ({navigation}) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
          color: "#fff"            
      },
      headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerLeft: <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => navigation.openDrawer()}> 
      <Image 
      source={require('./images/menu_burger.png')}
      style={{width: 24, height: 24, padding: 5, marginLeft: 5}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    })   } }, {   initialRouteName: 'DumontHome' })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without 'search term' or in this way:

```
navigate('route', {item:'search term'})
```